# How to call function in if structure in python?

Tags: function, python-2.7, conditional-statements

I try to call a function in python 2.7  in structure but I got an error.
Here is my code :

```
if not a % 2 == 0 : 
     '''here where i want to call t(x) function'''

else :
     print     'wrong!!!You must enter an Odd number '



def t(x) :
    return  2*x + 1
```

Comment: What error did you get? And could you post your attempt to call the function?

Comment: It's the problem !!! i don't know what command i should use.I used ( print ) but it didn't work.I wrote my code in question

Comment: Do you know how to call functions outside of an `if`? Because there's pretty much no difference between what you do outside or inside.

Comment: Not completely.. I know how call function in another function.But i couldn't call functions when i use (while) or ( for ) or (if) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your logic is wrong. You are telling the user to enter an odd number **if** they do enter an odd number, because of your `not`, which is unnecessary. Thus, you can just proceed as follows:

```
def t(x):
    return 2*x + 1

a = int(raw_input("Enter an even number: "))
while a % 2 != 0:
    print "You must enter an even number"
    a = int(raw_input("Enter an even number: "))

print t(a)
```

---

```
bash-3.2$ python foo.py
Enter an even number: 2
5
bash-3.2$ python foo.py
Enter an even number: 5
You must enter an even number
Enter an even number: 24
49
bash-3.2$
```

---

### If you just want to call a function in an `if` statement, do the following:

```
a = int(raw_input("Enter an even number: "))
if a % 2 == 0:
    print t(a)
else:
    print "You must enter an even number"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.but i didn't get my answer yet.What should i do if i want  to call functions in an (if) structure?